# Some process is removing first occurrence of backslash in JSP file. What would that be?

Tags: javascript, jsp, tomcat, servlets, backslash

My server uses Tomcat 7, HttpServlet, and JSP to construct html pages.

I have been loading my javascript files into the webpage with `<script src="source.js" />` approach so far.

Now, due to a requirement changes, I am embedding javascripts within JSP file directly. This way, javascripts and html gets loaded with a single http call.

Everything works as expected except that there is this one issue. The problem here is that first occurrence of `\` backslashes in JSP file are getting removed when a webpage gets loaded.

For instance,

```
<script>${string}.match(/\$/)</script>
```

will become

```
<script>${string}.match(/$/)</script>
```

These two regexes have totally different meanings. This makes many of regex matching to not work as expected anymore.

When JavaScript file was getting loaded with `<script src="" />` approach, 
this did not happen, as browser directly loads JS file from the server. However, once I embedded the javascripts into JSP, first occurrence of `\` is getting removed.

I am not familiar with Tomcat & Sevlet & JSP so I am not sure which one of these 3 components is causing this issue. Is there a configuration that I need to set to prevent tomcat from removing `\` from JSP file when it gets loaded?

If I cannot prevent tomcat/JSP from removing `\`, I could add a logic to actually escape `\` so that it gets loaded successfully in the browser. If that is the case, where can I find all list of characters that tomcat/JSP escapes/removes?

Comment: What makes you think this is happening?

Comment: Also, `${string}` is a JavaScript syntax error anyway.

Comment: Sounds like something wrong in whatever process does the embedding. Html parser won't change your script syntax

Comment: @mwilson ah OK. Well the code in the OP (other than `${string}` of course) should work just fine; that regex is perfectly OK and the backslash is there to correctly escape a `$`.

Comment: I see. I am using Tomcat & JSP and perhaps, servlet is removing backslashes during the view page loading. I will add Tomcat & JSP tag

Comment: `\` is an escape character, so you have to be careful when you use it. The EL configuration change you used changes the way that escape character is interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding `<%@ page isELIgnored="true" %>` to the top of the jsp file. JSP's Expression Language was the feature that was removing backslash `\` from javascripts.